# CSS overflow:hidden is not working

Tags: html, css

I was tryed to create a slider and the slider is working but only one part is not working .

> "`overflow:hidden`" **This part is not working**

Please tell me what is issue on my code . I will update this part .

This is my HTML:

```
<!-- Slider --><div class="slider-main">
<!-- <div class="container site-test_1"> -->
    <img id="slider-imge1" class="img-responsive" src="images/slider-images/slide_image-001.jpg" alt="Please wait..."/>
      <img id="slider-imge2" class="img-responsive" src="images/slider-images/slide_image-002.jpg" alt="Please wait..."/>
      <img id="slider-imge3" class="img-responsive" src="images/slider-images/slide_image-003.jpg" alt="Please wait..."/>
      <img id="slider-imge4" class="img-responsive" src="images/slider-images/slide_image-004.jpg" alt="Please wait..."/>
      <img id="slider-imge5" class="img-responsive" src="images/slider-images/slide_image-005.jpg" alt="Please wait..."/>
<!-- </div> -->
</div> <!-- End Slider -->
```

This is my CSS part:

```
.slider-main{
    width:100%;
    /* height:505px; */
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}


.slider-main img{
            width:100%;
            max-height:500px;
            overflow:hidden !important;
 }
```

Comment: can you create a demo with relevant code?

Comment: If I add a height on the `.slider-main`, it [seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/880oa6sm/). Please show us how it's not working.

Comment: white-space : nowrap; ? to keep img on a single line maybe .... Not enough code of yours to tell ...

Comment: It is working but only Small tablet landscape (800x600), Tablet portrait (768x1024), Tablet landscape (1024x768) . **It is not working in** Mobile portrait (320x480), Mobile landscape (480x320) Small tablet portrait (600x800)

Comment: It is working but only Small tablet landscape (800x600), Tablet portrait (768x1024), Tablet landscape (1024x768) . **IT IS NOT WORKING ONLY IN** Mobile portrait (320x480), Mobile landscape (480x320) Small tablet portrait (600x800)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Your max-height is bigger than slider-main div.

**Read details:** http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: It is working but only Small tablet landscape (800x600), Tablet portrait (768x1024), Tablet landscape (1024x768) . **IT IS NOT WORKING ONLY IN** Mobile portrait (320x480), Mobile landscape (480x320) Small tablet portrait (600x800)

Comment: for responsive codes use auto on width and height .

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `max-height: 500px` on the `.slider-main` instead:

```
.slider-main {
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Problem Solved

Comment: It is working but only Small tablet landscape (800x600), Tablet portrait (768x1024), Tablet landscape (1024x768) . **It is not working in** Mobile portrait (320x480), Mobile landscape (480x320) Small tablet portrait (600x800)

Comment: It is working but only Small tablet landscape (800x600), Tablet portrait (768x1024), Tablet landscape (1024x768) . **IT IS NOT WORKING ONLY IN** Mobile portrait (320x480), Mobile landscape (480x320) Small tablet portrait (600x800)

Comment: @GourabMazumder Are you using different devices? Mobile Browsers? Have you tried refreshing the pages after turning your device? (most Plugins do not check for window change)